Logging middleware throwing type errors
I am trying to create a middleware to log my requests when the response is sent to the user but my implementation:
import logger from "@/config/logger";
import { maskSensitiveData, stringify } from "@/lib/helpers/logger";
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";

const logRequests = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const {
    params = {},
    query = {},
    method = "GET",
    protocol = "HTTP",
    url = "/api",
    body = {},
  } = req;

  let clientIp = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || req.connection.remoteAddress;

  // Capture the original response method
  const originalJson = res.json.bind(res);

  // Wrap the response method
  res.json = function (data: any) {
    // Mask sensitive data
    const maskedParams = maskSensitiveData({ data: params });
    const maskedQuery = maskSensitiveData({ data: query });
    const maskedBody = maskSensitiveData({ data: body });
    const maskedData = maskSensitiveData({ data });

    // Log request and response information
    logger.debug(
      `IP: [${clientIp}] REQUEST: [PROTOCOL: ${protocol}, ENDPOINT: ${url}, METHOD: ${method}, BODY: ${stringify(
        maskedBody
      )}, QUERY: ${stringify(maskedQuery)}, PARAMS: ${stringify(
        maskedParams
      )}], RESPONSE: [STATUS: ${res.statusCode}, BODY: ${stringify(
        maskedData
      )}]`
    );

    // Call the original response method with the proper context
    return originalJson(data);
  } as unknown as Response; // Type assertion to match Response type

  // Continue to the next middleware
  next();
};

export default logRequests;

is throwing a type error:
Type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to type 'Send<any, Response<any, Record<string, any>>>'.
  Type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>' provides no match for the signature '(body?: any): Response<any, Record<string, any>>'

How do I reassign res.json method without triggering this error?

You are casting the wrapper function to Response when it should in fact be a function which returns a Response. This is what the error is telling you when it says.
Type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>' provides no match for the signature '(body?: any): Response<any, Record<string, any>>'

Because you then try to assign this type to res.json it complains and says it is not assignable. Change the type assertion to:
function {...} as unknown as Send<any, Response<any, Record<string, any>>>

You should not need the as unknown.
